# spring actuator for standalone spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

we have standalone spring boot application which triggers some quartz jobs based on triggers. it is standalone jar file , no application server involved.

i am planning to add Spring actuator to it. is it possible to add actuator to spring boot application which is not running on any application server.

i did search in google and spring.io website but haven't found any relevant info. if i can add can someone help me how to do it or any link for documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it...

Comment: i have added dependencies but when the application doesnt have server, how do i check the endpoints.

Comment: With JMX or register an exporter to have it export at regular intervals to something like graphite or other tooling.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the spring-boot-starter-web dependency to your pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I had the same issue and this resolved it for me.